# ggplot heatmap legend scale for multiple heatmaps in a shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, legend, heatmap

I have a shiny app, where I can generate 3 heatmaps depending on the selectinput field. The legend of heatmap 1 shows all 4 discrete variables "1" = "very good", "2" = "good", "3" = "bad", "4" = "ugly" as they appear in the heatmap. But in heatmap with selectinput Nr. 3 only "1" = "very good", "2" = "good", "3" = "bad" occur in the legend -> this is I think logic because only these values appear in the heatmap.
Is there a way to show all discrete values e.g. "1" = "very good", "2" = "good", "3" = "bad", "4" = "ugly" in the legend of all heatmaps (=selectinput 1, 3, 4)? Thank you.

My code:

```
# global.R
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# dataframe
df <- data.frame(
    test_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
    test_nr = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
                1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
    region = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", 
               "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", 
               "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
    test_value = c(3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 
                   4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3)
)
# named vector 
cols <-  c("1" = "limegreen", 
           "2" = "green", 
           "3" = "orange", 
           "4" = "red",
           "99"= "grey")
labels_legend <- c("1" = "very good", 
                   "2" = "good", 
                   "3" = "bad", 
                   "4" = "ugly",
                   "99" = NA)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$style(HTML("
    .tabbable > .nav > li > a {background-color: aqua;  color:black; width: 300PX;}
  ")),
    # App title ----
    titlePanel("TEST HEATMAP"),
    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(
        # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
        sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                     # Input: Select the id ----
                     selectInput(inputId = "test_id", 
                                 label = "Test ID", 
                                 choices = sort((unique(df$test_id))),
                                 selected = 1)
        ),
        # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
        mainPanel(width = 10,
                  # Output: Tabset plot,  ----
                  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                              tabPanel("tab1",
                                       fluidRow(
                                           column(width = 12,
                                                  plotOutput("test_plot"),
                                           )
                                       )
                              ),
                              tabPanel("tab2",
                              ),
                              tabPanel("tab3", 
                              )
                  )
        )  
    )
)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    var_testid <- reactive({input$test_id})
    
    output$test_plot <- renderPlot({
        
        req(var_testid())
        
        df <- df %>% 
            filter(test_id == as.integer(var_testid())) # filter testid

        gg1 <- ggplot(
            df, 
            aes(test_nr, region)) +
            geom_tile(aes(fill= factor(test_value)), height = 0.5) +
            geom_text(aes(label = test_value), size = 5, color = "black") + # text in tiles
            scale_colour_manual(
                values = cols, 
                breaks = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "99"),
                labels = labels_legend,
                aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")
            ) +
            theme(text = element_text(size = 14)) + # this will change all text size
            labs(title =  "Test (Individual heatmap)", x = "Region", y = "Event") +
            labs(fill = "Test") +
            theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12)) +
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, face = "bold", size = 12)) +
            theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "darkblue", 
                                           size = 1, linetype = "solid")
            ) 
        p1 <- egg::set_panel_size(gg1, height = unit(ncol(df), "cm"),
                                  width = unit(nrow(df), "cm"))
        cowplot::plot_grid(p1) # posiion plot left aligned with ncol2 but if big problems
    })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I would make sure `test_value` is a `factor`, before you call `ggplot` (instead of including in `aes` in one place...)...for your example, just add before `df$test_value = factor(df$test_value)`...in addition, add option `drop = FALSE` to your `scale_colour_manual`, and it should include all levels in your legend...I think this is more of a `ggplot` issue, and not related to shiny as far as I can tell...

Comment: Thank you Ben. drop = FALSE did the job. But I first had to declare the levels of my test_value. I found after your post something interesting: <https://github.com/thomasp85/ggraph/issues/164>  where I think the same issue is discussed regarding the legend behavior also in ggplot. Thanks for your help.